# octave in emacs (searching for program so such file or directory)

Tags: emacs, directory, octave, customization

I'm trying to run Octave from within emacs (I'm mostly a beginner at both but have the hang of emacs shortcuts now).  When I try *run-octave* as suggested [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Running-Octave-From-Within-Emacs.html), I get the message.

> Searching for file, no such file or directory, octave

Disclaimer: I'm using Windows Vista.
Octave is in **c:\Octave...**
the emacs default directory is 
**c:\users\username\**

and I added this to the _emacs file:

> > (autoload 'octave-mode "octave-mod" nil t)

```
    (setq auto-mode-alist
            (cons '("\\.m$" . octave-mode) auto-mode-alist))
```

> > (autoload 'run-octave "octave-inf" nil t)

Any tips on how to tell emacs where octave is?

Thank you for your help in advance,
Massagran

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make sure the octave binary, probably under "C:\Octave\bin", is in the search path.

To check this, right click your "Computer" icon on the Desktop or the Start Menu, right-click, select "Properties" and then select "Advanced System Settings". Click the "Environments variables" button and look for PATH. If you can't find the octave directory mentioned in this variable append ";C:\Octave\bin".

For more information on how to set the PATH variable check for example [here](http://www.question-defense.com/2009/06/22/modify-a-users-path-in-windows-vista-vista-path-environment-variable/).